# Why footer component is loaded before other components?

Tags: angular, angular6

Here I have been using two components Events & Footer. At the moment I have just a simple h1 tag in html but later I will have events to be displayed.

My problem here is Footer is being loaded before the event. I check the console console of footer is being loaded first then only event console is displayed.

These are the codes I am working on. Can anybody please help me? Thank You

### app.compoment.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<ng-snotify></ng-snotify>

<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

### events.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from 'src/app/services/event.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-events',
    templateUrl: './events.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

    events = [];
    constructor(private _eventService: EventService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("body");
    }
}
```

### footer.component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-footer',
    templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit():void {
        console.log('footer');
    }

}
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './components/events/events.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

import { SnotifyModule, SnotifyService, ToastDefaults } from 'ng-snotify';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EventsComponent,
 FooterComponent,
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this code it will happen. And nothing wrong in this code. In simple term, when you run your app , it will first run `app` file. Then angular will load components which we set in it's `module` file. You have assign a `footer` in `app.component.html`  which always load first then it will load all other components.

As you can see you have called `app-footer` in `app.component.html` not `app-events`. That's why it load `footer` first and then load `event`.

To prevent this situation :

**Solution 1:**

you can call `setTimeOut()` with few seconds.

**Solution 2:**

You can use `emit` and `subscribe` way. For example. When `event` load done , emit event and subscribe in app file. Based on that you can manage flag. Then based on flag you can set `footer` part.

**Solution 3:**

Pass the flag from routing files and fetch the flag. Based on that you can check that component is load or not.

In your **service** file :

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

public footer = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Now **emit** `footer` from your `.ts` file.

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.service.footer.emit();
}
```

Now **subscribe** in your footer's constructor

```
this.service.footer.subscribe(){
   this.flag = true; 
}
```

Now in **app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="flag">
   <app-footer> </app-footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give me example of solution 3

Comment: I have posted my answer.. is it the correct way. I am newbie learing for my technical exam.

Comment: @SS I have update my answer. Please implement that way. :)

Comment: just a confusion.. what is emit footer from your .ts file. which ts file you mean?

Comment: @SS emit from `ts` file mean your `events.component.ts` file.

Comment: sorry about asking every basic. But in the footer constructor I did  flag:boolean;

    constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {
        this._sharedService.footer.subscribe(
            this.flag = true
        )
     } .. but the footer is not appear

Comment: @SS  this._sharedService.footer.subscribe( res => { 
      this.flag = true
})

Comment: @SS Also put the console while subscribe . check what is the value of flag.

Comment: nothing at the console event at events.components.ts also nothing at console.

Comment: That mean you are doing something wrong while emit or subscribe event.

Comment: This is my events.component.ts 
ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.events = res,
                    this._sharedService.footer.emit()
                    console.log("event", this._sharedService.footer.emit());
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }

Comment: @SS Please follow my answer properly. You are doing wrong.

Comment: You have to just `emit()` from `ts` file and then you have to `subscribe()` in `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtuweb

can you check here. so sorry disturb you alot

Comment: I have checked , why you put `<app-events></app-events>` in app.component.html ? If you put then you don't need to use `emit` and `subscribe`.

Comment: Yes there should be router-outlet

Comment: If you don't put `<app-events></app-events>` in app.component.html then and then you need to use emit and subscribe stuff...

Comment: I have issue again with.. When I have multiple components. lets say i have events and special components. The flag is set true for events and if click on special then footer appears before.

Comment: @SS I suggest you to add a new question and explain your issue in details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048882/how-can-i-load-the-content-before-the-footer I have updated a new question

Answer (score 1):

> Why footer component is loaded before other components?

This is becaues "other components" are injected into `router-outlet` which is component as well. So what happens is:

1. Main layout is rendered with footer header and router-outlet
2. Router outlet gets initialized
3. Other components are injected into router outlet.

Comment: so how can I fix this problem. Can you plz help?

Answer (score 0):

I created a common service

### shared.services.ts

```
export class SharedService {

    loaded = false;

    constructor() { }

    setLoaded(cat: any) {
        this.loaded = cat;
    }

    checkLoaded() {
        return this.loaded;
    }
}
```

### footer.component.html

```
<p *ngIf="loaded">
  footer works!
</p>
```

### events.component.ts

```
constructor(private _eventService: EventService, private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this._sharedService.setLoaded(true)
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
```

### footer.component.ts

```
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.loaded = this._sharedService.checkLoaded();
        }, 1000);

    }
```