# How can I load the content before the footer?

Tags: angular, angular6

My footer is getting loaded before the content is loaded. I have multiple buttons in my navbar which when click opens a new component. When the user hits the events, it will emit after the event is loaded from the api. At this time footer is loading fine.

But after that I go to another link lets say special then footer is loading before the event.

I tried like below:

### events.component.ts

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

    events = [];
    constructor(private _eventService: EventService, private service: SharedService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                        this.events = res,
                        this.service.footer.emit(),
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

### shared.service

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {

    @Output() footer = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor() {}
}
```

### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    flag: boolean;

    constructor(private service: SharedService) {
        this.service.footer.subscribe(() => {
            this.flag = true ;
            console.log("Flag is ::: ",this.flag);
        })
    }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="footer" *ngIf="flag">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Here is a Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-662ndm

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but it looks likes you are trying to use a flag variable to control the display of the footer? Do you need to reset it to false every-time someone navigates?

Comment: Dont get your issue, what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: @lupus137 yes the flag is set to true everytime so when another page navigates footer show before content.

Comment: so you just need to reset the field first. I would recommend a way to do it, but I don't quite understand the set up at the moment.

Comment: @SS I think your ngOnInit is not firing on route change. Please check my answer.

Comment: @SS working sample is also added in my answer

Answer (score 2):

It is simple , as you emit event to make footer flag to true. In same way you have to again make one emit and subscribe to make it false.

**In your main service... E.x common.service.ts**

```
footerReset = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Now when ever you change component or call any API you just have to emit event...

```
this.common.footerReset.emit();
```

**In footer.component.ts**

In constructor...

```
this.common.footerReset().subscribe(() => {
    this.flag = false;
})
```

This will hide **footer** part. And you also call again emit when you got data from API. So it will automatically enable footer when you got data...

Comment: @SS Put console.log in footerReset subscribe and check what is the error ?

Comment: there is no error in console. In each component constructor I have this.common.footerReset emit and on ngOnInit  subscribe i set foot.emit() to call.

Comment: @SS I have to check your code. can you upload code ?

Comment: Can you give me stackblitz as before ?

Comment: @SS Your code is not works now. :( I didn't get any thing in console.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd1euj-stackoverflow-9wbff6 . This should work

Comment: @SS What is the issue , I can see every time footer is set after load component.

Comment: problem is same.. footer is displaying before events from api is loads. I can not show the api data in stackbliz

Comment: So emit the footer once you got data form API.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd1euj-stackoverflow-7eeims?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fspecial-component%2Fspecial-component.component.ts

Comment: See getData() I have added

Answer (score 1):

It's because your **ngOnInit** is not firing on your route change , So your code won't execute. I think it's known issue. There are some alternative to execute ngOnInit explicitly.It's explain in the below thread

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20112

I would suggest move your code  to the constructor , So constructor will call every time when the route change

```
 constructor(private service: SharedService) {
      this.service.footer.emit();
   }
```

Also call the change detection explicitly on your app component after subscribe to get the new changes in the model in to the view. It's because subscribe is from RXJS , So angular don't know the model is updated or not , So it won't call change detection. You can do the below tweak to say explicitly to angular something is changes in my model and call the change detection for me

```
 constructor(private service: SharedService,private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.service.footer.subscribe(() => {

      this.flag = true;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      console.log("Flag is ::: ", this.flag);
    })
  }
```

Here is the working sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd1euj-stackoverflow?file=src/app/app.component.ts